# design workflow in Eclipse for liferay

Tags: eclipse, liferay, workflow, liferay-6

I want to design workflow using Eclipse for Liferay CE.
Can anybody tell me how can i design kaleo workflow in Eclipse ?
I searched on the internet but could not find any facility for Community Edition (CE) to design our own workflow diagrammatically. Is there any reliable method other than kaleo for creating workflows for Liferay CE diagrammatically??Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By design, Liferay does not have a built-in UI in CE for creating Workflows, and does not provide a plugin for doing so. It's one of the goodies folks get when purchasing a subscription to EE.

Liferay EE has a built-in Kaleo Designer, and Liferay Developer Studio also has a Kaleo Designer for Java plugin to give you the same functionality inside Eclipse.

None of the free, open-source options (Liferay IDE or Liferay CE) have this feature.

That said, between the information in the [docs on Kaleo Designer](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/designing-a-kaleo-workflow-definition) and the [docs on Designing XML workflows](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-new-workflow-definitions), you should be able to design your definitions using XML.

That's probably not entirely satisfactory, but I think it's the best you're going to manage.

Comment: @nagi That's your best bet!